# Linux gdb not stopping at breakpoint in interrupt handler

Tags: gdb, interrupt-handling

I'm using a 3rd party library that sends an interrupt from a separate thread in the kernel (RHEL 7.9) to an interrupt handler that I am trying to debug.  I'm not able to get gdb (in Eclipse 4.11.0, CDT 9.7) to stop in my interrupt handler.  I'm not even able to use std::cout to print out anything inside my handler.

The vendor uses Visual Studios and is able to get the debugger to stop in his interrupt handlers but wasn't familiar enough with gdb or Linux to know if it's possible with gdb.

I've been able to get other interrupt handlers from this same library to work but am having trouble with a specific handler that I'd like to step through so that I can figure out why it's not working properly.

Is there some setting or some step that I'm missing so that I can properly walk through my interrupt handler?  Maybe a different technique to try to follow along with what is actually going on inside my interrupt handler?

**Edit**: I've tried using std::cout to print values I'm interested and outputting to a text file but neither have worked.

Comment: So you're saying this interrupt handler is not called if you debug with gdb? But it is called if you don't debug?

Comment: No, if I try to debug it with gdb it doesn't stop in either case but in the one case it does what it's supposed to do.  The one case where it isn't working properly I need it to stop and it doesn't.